# KSV master wait event?

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

I have a third party application framework (Oracle ADF) issuing the following SQL command:

```
insert into "PS_TXN" values (:1, :2, :3, :4, sysdate)
```

Object `PS_TXN` is a table in another schema, accessed via a synonym of the same name in my current schema.

There are no database triggers on `PS_TXN`.

When this SQL gets submitted, the application hangs indefinitely.  I see in the Oracle database that the session is waiting on event "KSV master wait".  The SQL also has insanely high statistics associated with it for a simple `INSERT`.  Including:

- Users Executing = 1
- Buffer Gets = 11,641,723
- CPU Time = 2,263,425,538
- IO Interconnect Bytes = 4,266,975,232
- Physical Read Requests = 277,181
- Physical Read Bytes = 4,266,975,232

Does anyone know what "KSV Master Wait" event is and/or how a simple insert into a table with no triggers could consume so many resources?

Comment: This is the database acting strange rather than a problem in the code. Recommended for move to the DBA stack exchange. Looks like it is doing something really odd allocating the underlying storage for the table (possibly the very first insert into a new table)

Comment: It's not a new table nor an empty one.  But I'll consider posting on the DBA SE.  Thanks